# `Result in Result` with actix-web and mysql

Tags: mysql, rust, actix-web

I am very VERY new to rust (coming from c++ & go), and I am trying to implement a simple rest API backed by a mysql database to learn the language.

I followed various examples from in actix (https://github.com/auth0-blog/actix-diesel-auth/blob/master/src/handlers.rs for instance) and came up with this:

```rust
use std::vec::Vec;
use actix_web::{web, HttpResponse};
use mysql::*;
use mysql::prelude::Queryable;

use crate::models::{self, user::User};

// Handler for GET /users
pub async fn get_users(pool: mysql::Pool) -> HttpResponse {

    let op =  web::block(move || 
        get_all_watches(pool)).await;

    match op {
        Ok(users) => {

            match users {
                Ok(users) => HttpResponse::Ok().json(users),
                Err(err) => HttpResponse::InternalServerError().body(err.to_string()),
            }
        },
        Err(err) => HttpResponse::InternalServerError().body(err.to_string()),
    }

}

fn get_all_users(pool: mysql::Pool) -> Result<Vec<models::user::User>> {

    let mut conn = pool.get_conn()?;

    let watches = conn
    .query_map(
        "SELECT userId, name, fisrtname, email from users",
        |(user_id, name, firstname, email)| {
            User { user_id, name, firstname, email }
        },
    )?;

    Ok(watches)
}
```

`get_all_users` returns `Result<Vec<Watch, Global>, Error>` that is wrapped into a `Result<Result<Vec<Watch, Global>, Error>, BlockingError>` from the `web::block`.

I find the `match { match {` quite inelegant for such a simple operation. Is the `web::block` the *right* thing to do when interacting directly with a database (without `Diesel` as ORM like in the auth0 example) from `actix`? Is there an idiomatic way to handle this flow ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you see nested `match`, you can usually convert that to one `match`:

```rust
match op {
    Ok(Ok(users)) => HttpResponse::Ok().json(users),
    Ok(Err(err)) => HttpResponse::InternalServerError().body(err.to_string()),
    Err(err) => HttpResponse::InternalServerError().body(err.to_string()),
}
```

Comment: If the error types are the same you could also use [`flatten`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.flatten) on nightly or once it's stable.

Comment: @cafce25 You can also use or patterns. But they're not the same :(